# In TeamCity, how can I check if the previous build failed?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to notify users that the successful build fixed the previously broken build.  I haven't found a simple way to check if the last build failed.

Is there a parameter / variable I can check as a condition for the build step, or one that I can use in code, e.g. Python?

I'm on TeamCity 2020.1.2, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, notifications can be sent by creating notification rules based on events.  In this case the event is *Only notify on the first successful build after failed*.  See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/adding-notification-rules.html#Which+Events+Will+Trigger+Notifications)

For me, I actually wanted to run code, rather than let TeamCity do the notification, so here's what I did:

- In TeamCity parameters, I created an environment variable (I called it *TEAMCITY_BUILD_TYPE_ID*) with the value *%system.teamcity.buildType.id%*
- In my build step, I have some Python code that calls the TeamCity API with the path:  `f"builds/?locator=buildType:(id:{os.environ.get('TEAMCITY_BUILD_TYPE_ID')}),count:1"`
- I then checked the result, and if it returns a build with *status* == *"FAILURE"*, then I know that the last build failed

Comment: The out-of-the-box notifications rules can react on different events, in particular "Only notify on the first successful build after failed". The description says: "Check this option to receive notifications when only the first successful build occurs after a failed build. Notifications about subsequent successful builds will not be sent." More details [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/adding-notification-rules.html#Which+Events+Will+Trigger+Notifications). Does it look like what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @YanSklyarenko, that's almost what I'm looking for.  It looks like that allows a user to subscribe to notifications.  What I'm doing is slightly different, by sending a notification to a Slack channel, so you could say the Slack channel is the subscriber, rather than an individual.  However, I presume that what you've shared would work for most people who are looking to do something similar to me.  The doc link for my version of TeamCity is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2020.1/subscribing-to-notifications.html#Which+Events+Will+Trigger+Notifications).

Comment: The article you referenced also contains the info about the Slack notifier, which I believe should work the same way as the email notifier and react to the same set of events.